# What are the mechanics of scanf() in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, loops, scanf

So I started learning C today, and as an exercise I was told to write a program that asks the user for numbers until they type a <kbd>0</kbd>, then adds the even ones and the odd ones together. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>;

int main() {
    int esum = 0, osum = 0;
    int n, mod;

    puts("Please enter some numbers, 0 to terminate:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n != 0) {
        mod = n % 2;
        switch(mod) {
        case 0:
            esum += n;
            break;
        case 1:
            osum += n;
        }
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    printf("The sum of evens:%d,\t The sum of odds:%d", esum, osum);
    return 0;
}
```

My question concerns the mechanics of the `scanf()` function. It seems that when you enter several numbers at once separated by spaces (eg. `1 22 34 2 8`), the `scanf()` function somehow remembers each distinct numbers in the line, and steps through the while loop for each one respectively. Why/how does this happen?

Example interaction within command prompt:

```
-> Please enter some numbers, 0 to terminate:  
42 8 77 23 11 (enter)  
0 (enter)  
-> The sum of evens:50,     The sum of odds:111
```

I'm running the program through the command prompt; it's compiled for win32 platforms with Visual Studio.

Comment: C curricula really need to stop using introducing people to bad practices such as using `scanf`. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to append a semicolon to the `#include` directive.

Comment: Is that because the semicolon in the preprocessed include file ends the statement? Or because the compiler inherently 'knows better' by some other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you're calling scanf() each time you go through the loop; each time you call scanf() with the arguments "%d" and &n, it reads a single integer into the variable n and advances to the position immediately after that integer in the input stream.

You can sort of think of the input stream as a "string" of sorts.  Suppose I typed "25 16 0"; after scanf() reads the first integer, the input stream becomes "16 0"; if you call scanf() again, you'll read the integer 16 and the input string becomes "0".

Comment: Is it possible in / directly after the scanf() call to tell it 'only take the first int you find' / explicitly clear the input stream of the leftover string?

Comment: The way you're calling scanf() right now, you're indeed telling it to 'only take the first int you find'.  If you were to use, for example, scanf("%d %d", &a, &b), then scanf() would read the first two integers it finds into a and b.

As for the second part of your question, I'm not sure if there's a standard way to "clear the whole stream", but you can make scanf ignore everything until the end of the line by changing "%d" to "%d%*s".  You should test it out and see what happens!

Comment: If you want more information about the gritty details of scanf(), especially how to use that first argument, I recommend reading the man page: http://www.netadmintools.com/html/3scanf.man.html

Admittedly, this is not easy to read, but if you can get through it, you will really understand how to use scanf().

Comment: @Riemannliness Use scanf ("%d", &a); fflush(stdin); scanf ("%d", &b); This way every time you use fflush(stdin); the input buffer is flushed (cleared).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `scanf` function gets its input from the standard input *stream*. It is called *stream* for a reason: everything you enter is put into that stream, and `scanf` reads that stream. Whatever you put into the input stream will stay there until something like `scanf` gets it out of there.

In other words, `scanf` doesn't really "remember" anything. It is the input stream that does all the "remembering".